# tengo un error al intentar entrar a mi vista show.blade.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Este es el ProductController donde guardo el return con la vista show

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
      return view('products.show');
    }
}
```

Esta es la vista show

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('body-class', 'profile-page')

@section('content')
  <div class="page-header header-filter" data-parallax="true" style="background-image: url('/img/city-profile.jpg');"></div>
   <div class="main main-raised">
     <div class="profile-content">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6 ml-auto mr-auto">
             <div class="profile">
               <div class="avatar">
                 <img src="/img/faces/christian.jpg" alt="Circle Image" class="img-raised rounded-circle img-fluid">
               </div>
               <div class="name">
                 <h3 class="title">Christian Louboutin</h3>
                 <h6>Designer</h6>
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-just-icon btn-link btn-dribbble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-just-icon btn-link btn-twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-just-icon btn-link btn-pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="description text-center">
           <p>An artist of considerable range, Chet Faker &#x2014; the name taken by Melbourne-raised, Brooklyn-based Nick Murphy &#x2014; writes, performs and records all of his own music, giving it a warm, intimate feel with a solid groove structure. </p>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6 ml-auto mr-auto">
             <div class="profile-tabs">
               <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-icons justify-content-center" role="tablist">
                 <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link active" href="#studio" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                     <i class="material-icons">camera</i> Studio
                   </a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#works" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                     <i class="material-icons">palette</i> Work
                   </a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#favorite" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                     <i class="material-icons">favorite</i> Favorite
                   </a>
                 </li>
               </ul>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="tab-content tab-space">
           <div class="tab-pane active text-center gallery" id="studio">
             <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-3 ml-auto">
                 <img src="/img/examples/studio-1.jpg" class="rounded">
                 <img src="/img/examples/studio-2.jpg" class="rounded">
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3 mr-auto">
                 <img src="/img/examples/studio-5.jpg" class="rounded">
                 <img src="/img/examples/studio-4.jpg" class="rounded">
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="tab-pane text-center gallery" id="works">
             <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-3 ml-auto">
                 <img src="/img/examples/olu-eletu.jpg" class="rounded">
                 <img src="/img/examples/clem-onojeghuo.jpg" class="rounded">
                 <img src="/img/examples/cynthia-del-rio.jpg" class="rounded">
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3 mr-auto">
                 <img src="/img/examples/mariya-georgieva.jpg" class="rounded">
                 <img src="/img/examples/clem-onojegaw.jpg" class="rounded">
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="tab-pane text-center gallery" id="favorite">
             <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-3 ml-auto">
                 <img src="/img/examples/mariya-georgieva.jpg" class="rounded">
                 <img src="/img/examples/studio-3.jpg" class="rounded">
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3 mr-auto">
                 <img src="/img/examples/clem-onojeghuo.jpg" class="rounded">
                 <img src="/img/examples/olu-eletu.jpg" class="rounded">
                 <img src="/img/examples/studio-1.jpg" class="rounded">
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
@include('includes.footer')
@endsection
```

Esta es la imagen que muestra el error en laravel[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Route::post('/products/{id}', 'ProductController@show');

Comment: ah ya lo pillo, deberia ser un Route::get jaja que tonta ya esta, gracias @Shaz

Comment: no tengo suficientes puntos pero te vote hacia arriba jaja :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando accedes por medio del navegador (barra de navegación) a un sitio web, estás haciendo una solicitud GET al servidor, así que debes modificar el verbo de la ruta definida en Laravel para que funcione:

```
Route::get('/products/{id}', 'ProductController@show');
```